# Getting time complexity error

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I am trying to solve this question : https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/add-one-to-number
But I am always getting

> Time Complexity Error :
>
> Runtime Error. Your submission stopped because of a runtime error. ex:
> division by zero, array index out of bounds, uncaught exception You
> can try testing your code with custom input and try putting debug
> statements in your code.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong in my solution?

```
vector<int> Solution::plusOne(vector<int> &A) {
    vector<int> res;
    int rem=1;
    while(A[0]==0 && A.size()>1){
        A.erase(A.begin());
    }
    for(vector<int>::reverse_iterator it=A.rbegin();it!=A.rend();++it){
        int t = *it;
        t=t+rem;
        res.insert(res.begin(), t%10);
        rem = t/10;
    }
    while(rem!=0){
        res.insert(res.begin(), rem);
        rem/=10;
    }
    
    return res;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Rather than erasing and inserting, you should consider overwriting.  Erasing (removal) may be an unnecessary operation.

Comment: What happens if plusOne is called when A is empty?  Consider A[0].

Comment: Don't remove the leading zeros; don't create a copy; modify `A` directly and then don't output leading zeros when you print it. You're also done as soon as a specific condition is true (I'll leave you to figure out the condition).

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is failing because it is taking too long to compute. Erasing and inserting at the beginning of a vector is very expensive. For example, if the input vector had a million zeros at the beginning and you looped through and used erase to remove each one it would take a really long time because the vector needs to recreate itself each time minus the first element. The answer is to find a way to do the computation while modifying the vector as little as possible.

Edit:
It is also possible that interviewbit is tracking how the computation time scales. For example if a solution has a time complexity of `O(N^2)` and the correct solution would have a time complexity of `O(N)` or `O(1)` then that would be the definition of a time complexity error. A solution with `O(N^2)` may take 4 ms for an input of size `n` and 16 ms for an input of size `2n`. If they were expecting linear or constant time complexity then the solution would fail.

Comment: Time complexity "quantifies the amount of time taken by an algorithm to run as a function of the length of the string representing the input" (wikipedia). The only reason a runtime time complexity error would occur is if something was tracking the time taken for a given input.

Comment: Is it a time complexity error if the function faults?  If I time the duration of computation until a result is returned and no result is ever returned, I say it is.

Comment: If the function faults then it is some other classification of runtime error. If the duration of computation is infinite and the time complexity limit is finite then the program must be terminated and a classification of time complexity error is applied.